# Show that $\lim_{n→∞}x_n$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $x_1 ∈ (0, 1)$ be a real number between $0$ and $1.$
>
> For $n > 1,$ define $x_{n+1} = x_n − x^{n+1}_n.$
>
> Then show that $\lim_{n→∞}x_n$ exists.

I'm absolutely clueless what to use.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a monotonic and bounded sequence of real numbers has a limit.  Show by induction that $x_n \in (0, 1)$ and thus (using the given recurrence) that $(x_n)$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$.

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo in your question, as with $n>1$ there is no definition for $x_2$

another way of looking at it is to divide the recurrence equation by $x_n$ which gives
$$ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = 1 - x_n^n
$$

now multiplying these equations we get:

$$ x_{n+1} = x_1\prod_{k=1}^n (1- x_k^k)
$$